# validate using ExpressiveAnnotations using AssertThat from different viewmodels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressiveannotations

I'm trying to use `ExpressiveAnnotations` to validate my form. I have two viewmodels wherein the 2nd model is dependent to the 1st model. Is this possible using this library?

Thank you.

```
public class ViewModel
    {    
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? Start { get; set; }

        [AssertThat("End >= Start", ErrorMessage = "You cannot set end date before the start of leave.")]
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        [Display(Name = "End ")]
        public DateTime? End { get; set; }
    }


public class ViewModel1
{
    [AssertThat("Date1 < Start", ErrorMessage = "Start cannot be before Date1.")]
    [AssertThat("Date1 >= End", ErrorMessage = "Start cannot be after Date1.")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date1 ")]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? Date1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: never mind.. I fixed my model. Combined the two in one model.

Comment: Sorry it's too late. I haven't tried this but why can't you inherit your second view model. i.e., ViewModel1 : ViewModel